# eevee smoke/volume not being occluded

Tags: eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

Been touching upon EEvEE every so often depending on what kind of image quality I'm looking for at the moment, and for the first time I am adding smoke. More specifically Glowing Smoke, as in "Magic". However, the volume material shows through other objects in front of it.

[image]

You can see more clearly on the right the yellow magic outlines the entire horn, even the part that is embedded into the skull and hiding behind the hair. I have played around with the material's Blend and Shadow Modes, Refraction and Subsurface Translucency, and all the settings connected with Volumetrics (and Shadows), but it does not seem to make a difference. Anything I am missing or is this a bug?

Blender 2.92.0 2021-02-24 16.25

**EDIT**
I made a new project with nothing in it, I imported the right model, and applied the smoke on the horn, and brought up the Emission Strength only. The whole thing still shone through.

**EDIT2**
When putting in the ordinary geometry from the Add menu and shaping them approximately to the model, the smoke is occluded.

Comment: Share blend - smoke+hair only if issue persist ...

Comment: @vklidu Here is the blend, no bakes, all domains set to Replay. Still big tho.
https://www.edwardleuf.org/x/intro2b.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this file (2.93) or try with some new file to eliminate something specific to your issued file.

Left Smoke sim / Right only Volumetric material ... both seems to be working.

[image]

[image]

---

### Edit

That was real issue hunting ... the main reason is this [Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169219) ... for Eevee it is too small step in depth when volumetric is calculated. And I'm not sure there would be solution for you. Here is example with solved issue ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

... but the only one solution I found ... crop the area under *Render Properties > Volumetrics >* **Start/ End** and increase **Samples** up to 256 ... also don't use **Distribution** around 1, use some low value.

[image]

That means very limited range of volumetric effect depend on Camera distance.

Your file has other things that can cause some issues ... like extremely high Viewport **Clip End** that generates flickering, some of your objects like unicorn's hair use wrong Normals direction, and it is always better to have *Applied Scale* for all objects if possible ... not the case for volumetric issue, but any time I tried to switch to Eevee all computer crashed that never happened for many years to me.

Here is a file in condition that I expected you will share (hair+horn) that takes only 0.6 MB.

[image]

If you are looking for just an effect like glowing horn, you can use new object type *Volume* with **[Mesh to Volume](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199176/2214)** modifier instead of Smoke simulation ... or even easier animate emission material for horn with some high value and enable **Bloom** in *Render Properties*.

Comment: Well, can't figure it out. I've tried to make your file mimic mine and visa-versa but the results don't seem to change in either (yours is blocked and mine isn't). I even made a new file, imported the model above, applied the smoke and it shines through.

Comment: You are saying that my file opened on your PC is OK? Try "Load Factory Setting" ...

Comment: Ah, there we go. Clipping. I always forget about that. Most often I set these things as close and as far as possible, but only if I have a large environment. And I know I can use Emission or static volumes, but I do want that little variance that comes with smoke simulations. Anyways, thanks.